# switch case loop with onListItemClick

Tags: android, android-listview, switch-statement

I have a listview, and can start activities with onListItemClick using switch cases manually:

**case 0: case 1: case 2: .......**

but I want to get count of  listview items dynamicly, and use them like case loop : **case i++** .I it possible ?

what I want to make:

```
...
    setListAdapter(adapter);

      @Override
        public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
                super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

                final int index = position;
                switch (position) {
                for (int i=0; i< l.getCount(); i++){
                case i:
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setClass(getActivity(), Activity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                }
    }
```

Comment: i=0 and i<l.getCount() means the same click listener for all the items, then why do you want to assign click listener this way?

Comment: Brief your question more. What exactly you want to achieve ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call same class on each item click then you dont need for loop.Just pass the intent onItemClickListener() its done.And if you want to pass different classes according to ItemClick then I think everytime you have to check for the position and pass the Intent according to Position.